Enhanced Miller Rabin outcome for composite numbers
I'm going through the Enhanced MR test cited in FIPS 186-5, in which it is mentioned that a composite number can be  COMPOSITE WITH FACTOR  or  COMPOSITE AND NOT A POWER OF A PRIME.
When I tested this on the same modulus for longer number(approx 100) of times I observed that the enhanced MR test is returning  COMPOSITE WITH FACTOR  instead of  COMPOSITE AND NOT A POWER OF A PRIME.
So I would like to understand if the outcome of this enhanced MR test depends on the random witness chosen for the composite numbers or is it the case that enhanced MR test is always deterministic in returning  COMPOSITE WITH FACTOR  or  COMPOSITE AND NOT A POWER OF A PRIME  for a given composite number for any random number that is generated in the range 1<b<w-1 as witness. Can you please share your thoughts.
For example, like for primality test if I keep the iteration count to 64, it provides a bit strength of 2^-128(that is the probability of generating a bad prime). Likewise is there a way we can estimate the probability of allowing a bad composite number as RSA modulus based on the iterations that we apply on the enhanced MR test on the composite number.
From code I can confirm that, after increasing the iteration count to 64 and I can see more consistency in the outcome of enhanced MR test on the composite number. But im unable to express the iteration count in terms of probability so that I can chose the lowest possible number for the probability of 2^-128.

Repeating the enhanced MR test to the number of iterations of primality test is giving me the very accurate result about the number is composite with factor or composite with power of no prime.  But if there is any standard reference or proof that demonstrates this it would be helpful.

If you want to be absolutely certain you generate a prime, see the Shawe-Taylor algorithm in FIPS 186-5.

As I checked regarding the same in CMUF forum. Based on the discussion, I ran enhanced MR test through 25 iterations(FIPS 186-5 IG C.F) until it returns COMPOSITE AND NOT A POWER OF A PRIME. I ran this test over primes/sub primes/prime powers and in all these scenarios I got same expected outcome from the test. [converted from answer to comment by moderator]

@sg777: It's unclear to me why you want to run the algorithm until it returns PROVABLY COMPOSITE AND NOT A POWER OF A PRIME. That will be easy for some numbers, like the product of two large random distinct primes; and hard for others that have many small prime factors, e.g. the 1024-bit 0xdbd59daadac56c9cbf74d8875e1a7666d94305d693901ccecafc2bb3b43d74a6a91656b600288e548b7c9dbfb40eec6b0da3bbf1cf4c29e6e2c00435bf591ef4fe2f5569c2ef5731443e05f21efdf28ca373a542aed6eca8b91c8a1a30880ab594ed70ee8be31b13ba7fb8dbec9e6d6b289b7183e1bad622e2386aa589fd7457 which will often yield COMPOSITE WITH FACTOR.

Agree, but the main intention of this test case is only to check if the composite number not a power of prime. By running upto 25 iterations I can reject the numbers with greater confidence.
Initially i tried with the approach of running MR for 25 iterations and in all iterations if the outcome is not a power of prime I'm accepting it, but since the outcome is depending on b value chosen, due to which lets say if the outcome of MR returns composite then in that case the previous outcomes of the MR test is not adding any confidence to final outcome.

My objective is either to accept the composite with no prime power or reject the composite with factor with higher confidence. I don't know how to achieve the former case so i chose to reject the composite with factor with greater confidence. Please correct me if im wrong.

Are you looking for "composite with no prime power" as in the above comment, or for "composite not a power of a prime" as in the question and the test? That's not the same thing! e.g. 75=3×5² and 225=3²×5² both are a composite not a power of a prime, but neither is a composite with no prime power. We can quite efficiently determine if a given integer is a composite not a power of a prime, but I don't know how to efficiently determine if a given large integer is a composite with no prime power.

I'm looking for composite not a power of power.  The exact definition from NIST 800-89 is as follows:
Not a power of a prime: Check that n is not a power of a prime, i.e., there are no integers b ≥ 2, c ≥ 2 such that n = b^c.
In a given composite number if I can able to determine these numbers I can avoid these numbers and can accept rest.

@sg777: indeed there is just what you describe in NIST 800-89, but that sentence is wrong. The condition "there are no integers $b≥2$, $c≥2$ such that $n=b^c$" is stronger than the condition "n is not a power of a prime". And I'm not sure that getting PROVABLY COMPOSITE AND NOT A POWER OF A PRIME out of the enhanced MR test ensures that stronger condition. I asked!

@fgrieu Thanks a lot.

The Enhanced MR test of FIPS 186-5 is passed an odd integer $w$ to be tested for primality, and returns one of 3 possible outcomes

PROBABLY PRIME
PROVABLY COMPOSITE WITH FACTOR, and a factor of $w$ in $\bigl[3,\lfloor w/3\rfloor\bigr]$
PROVABLY COMPOSITE AND NOT A POWER OF A PRIME

PROVABLY can be removed from the statement of 2 or 3. Make sure to distinguish proBably from proVably: outcome 1 does not quite imply that $w$ is prime!

(does) the outcome of this enhanced MR test depends on the random witness chosen ?

Yes, except when the input $w$ is prime or small.
More precisely: possible outcomes according to the nature of $w$



nature of $w$ being tested
possible outcomes
remark




Prime
1



Composite and a prime power
1 or 2
1 is rare,or impossible for small enough $w$


Composite not a prime power
1 or 2 or 3
1 is rare,or impossible for small enough $w$



As observed in the question, for some pseudorandom values of the witness $d$ (generated at step 4.1 of the algorithm), the outcome is 2 for a composite $w$ that's not a power of a prime. The outcome can also be 2 when $w$ is a power of a prime. For example for $d=33$, the outcome is 2 with the factor $g=11$ returned both when $w=77$ and $w=121$, with only the later being a power of a prime.
If $w$ is random, outcome 2 is not uncommon. If $w$ is large and random among integers having no small prime factors (e.g. thanks to a sieving step when generating $w$), outcome 2 is rare. For products of two large distinct prime factors and low iteration count, outcome 2 is even rarer than outcome 1 is. There are values of $w$ making outcome 2 common for low iteration count, even though $w$ is a composite not a power of a prime. An example is the 2048-bit
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



for primality test if I keep the iteration count to 64, it provides a bit strength of 2^-128 (that is the probability of generating a bad prime)

That probability is actually much smaller. Regardless of how $w$ was generated, for $i$ iterations, there's probability below $2^{-2i}$ that the outcome is  PROBABLY PRIME  when $w$ is not actually prime, that is probability below $2^{-256}$ for $i=64$. And if the candidate prime $w$ is large and generated randomly (including among integers having no prime factors below some limit), the probability is so much lower that for 1024-bit $w$, $i=7$ yields probability below $2^{-100}$ of generating a composite. See table B.1 or this, and for the math appendix C.1 and it's references.
Notice that for the purpose of generating primes, we can ignore the difference there is between outcomes 2 and 3. That's the case for all purposes in FIPS 186-5.
Update: @poncho gives a nice proof of the NOT A POWER OF A PRIME part of outcome 3.
